# get route component by route name in Angular2

Tags: angular

Is there a simple way to get the route component defined in @RouteConfig by route name?
I tried following code with underscore and it works but I need to know the simplest way.

```
   let annotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', MyApp)[0].configs; 
   let route = _.findWhere( annotations, {name: 'RouteName' } );
   let component = route.component;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get this information from an `Instruction`

```
router.generate(['/RouteName']).component.componentType;
```

Comment: Great, was about to try it in a Plunker, I guess I can skip it then ;-) Thanks for the feedback!